# Dynamic resize of <p:layoutUnit> can it be done?

Tags: primefaces

I asked this question on the PrimeFaces forum and got no response, so I figured I would try here.

- Using PrimeFaces 3.0 -

I have a page that contains [p:layout] with a [p:layoutUnit] that I want to resize dynamically in a backing bean.
There are two ways I am using this:

1) A [p:commandButton] calls a backing bean that sets the bean property for the size parameter in the p:layoutUnit component.
I can do this, but in order to make it work, I have to set ajax="false" and update="@all" (probably don't need the update) in order to force a page redraw.
When I do that, the width of the  is reset and the panel draws at the desired width.

2) I have a [g:map] component with p:ajax event="overlaySelect" 
I want to resize the panel in a similar way when the overlayEvent is activated.
The problem I am having is that I can't seem to make the [p:overlayUnit] resize without a complete page refresh, and I can't seem to get the overlaySelect event to cause the page to refresh (or it does not do so in a manner that will resizze the [p:layoutUnit]. It will resize if I do a page refresh.

I have two questions:
1) Is there a way to dynamically resize a [p:layoutUnit] component without having to do a complete page refresh? I can't seem to make it work any other way.

2) Is there a way to force the [p:ajax event="overlaySelect"]  to force a complete page refresh so I can force the resize like I do in my first scenario?

Thanks

Here is the page code if anyone is interested:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view id="mapPolygonView" contentType="text/html" beforePhase="#{mappingSessionBean.beforePhase}"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ezcomp"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<html>
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="./resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="./resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="./resources/js/Raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-layout-north {
                z-index:20 !important;
                overflow:visible !important;;
            }
            .ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
                overflow:visible !important;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Map Polygon Edit</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true" onResize="onResizeEvent(event)" >
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="82" resizable="true" >
                <h:form id="formNorth" prependId="=false" >
                    <p:outputPanel id="panelNorth"  >
                        <comp:header id="headerComp" />
                        <comp:menuBar id="menuBarComp" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </h:form >
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="layoutWest" position="west" size="#{mappingSessionBean.optionPanelWidth}" resizable="true" collapsible="true" header="Options" >
                <h:form id="formWest" prependId="=false" >
                    <p:outputPanel id="panelWest"  >
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 98%;" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayOptionGridWest}" >
                            <h:commandLink value="Add Polygon" style="margin-left: 5px;" action="#{mappingSessionBean.addNewPolyAction}" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disableAddPolygonLink}" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayAddPolygonLink}" update="@form :formCenter:mapPanel :formCenter:polygonAddPanelComp:polygonAddPanel" />
                            <h:commandLink value="Edit Polygon" style="margin-left: 5px;" action="#{mappingSessionBean.editPolyAction}" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disableEditPolygonLink}" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayEditPolygonLink}" update=":formCenter:messageComp:messagePnl" />
                            <h:commandLink value="Disable Polygon" style="margin-left: 5px;" action="#{mappingSessionBean.disablePolyAction}" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disableDisablePolygonLink}" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayDisablePolygonLink}" update=":formCenter:messageComp:messagePnl" />
                            <h:commandLink value="Locate Address" style="margin-left: 5px;" action="#{mappingSessionBean.locateAddressAction}" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disableLocateAddressLink}" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayLocateAddressLink}" update="@form" />
                            <p:separator />
                            <h:outputText value="Locate Address:" style="margin-left: 5px;" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayLocateAddress}" />
                            <p:inputTextarea value="#{mappingSessionBean.searchAddress}" style="width: 125px;; height: 40px;" autoResize="false" maxHeight="40" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayLocateAddress}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Find" action="#{mappingSessionBean.findAddressAction()}" update="@form :formCenter:gmap :formCenter:messageComp:messagePnl" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayLocateAddress}" />
                            <p:separator rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayLocateAddress}" />
                            <p:commandButton id="btn3" value="Save Polygon" style="width: 135px;" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disableSavePolyBtn}" onclick="confirmDialog.show();" update="@form :formCenter:gmap :formCenter:messageComp:messagePnl" />
                            <p:commandButton id="btn5" value="Refresh Polygons" style="width: 135px;" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disablePolyBtns}" action="#{mappingSessionBean.refreshPolygons}" update="@form :formCenter:gmap" />
                            <p:commandButton id="btn6" value="Test State" style="width: 135px;" action="#{mappingSessionBean.testStatePolygon}" onclick="confirmDialog.show();" update="@form :formCenter:gmap" />
                            <p:separator />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="width: 145px;" >
                            <h:outputText value="Map Height: " style="margin-left: 5px;" />
                            <p:commandButton value="+" action="#{mappingSessionBean.polyMapPlus}" update=":formCenter:gmap" />
                            <p:commandButton value="-" action="#{mappingSessionBean.polyMapMinus}" update=":formCenter:gmap" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 98%;" >
                            <p:commandButton value="Restore Original" style="width: 135px;" disabled="#{mappingSessionBean.disablePolyBtns}" action="${mappingSessionBean.restoreOriginalPolyView}" update=":formCenter:gmap :formEast:panelEast"  />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <comp:polygonAddPanel id="polygonAddPanelComp" />
                        <comp:polygonEditPanel id="polygonEditanelComp" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </h:form >
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true"  >
                <h:form id="formCenter" prependId="false" >
                    <p:idleMonitor onidle="idleDialog.show();" timeout="#{sessionBean1.timeout}" >
                        <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{sessionBean1.idleListener}" update="@form" />
                    </p:idleMonitor>
                    <comp:message id="messageComp" message="#{sessionBean1.message}" />
                    <p:outputPanel id="mapAddPolyPanel" >
                        <h:panelGrid id="mapAddPolyPanelGrid" style="width: 90%; height: 35px; margin-top: 10px; display: block; position: relative;" columns="4" >
                            <h:outputText value="Account:" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 250px;" value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedAccount}" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{sessionBean1.custAccountList}"/>
                                <p:ajax listener="#{mappingSessionBean.accountSelectAction}" update="polyGrpDD gmap" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <h:outputText value="Polygon Group:" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="polyGrpDD" style="width: 250px;" value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyGroup}" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{mappingSessionBean.polygonGroupList}"/>
                                <p:ajax listener="#{mappingSessionBean.polyGroupSelectAction}" update="@form :formEast:panelEast :formWest:panelWest gmap" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:outputPanel id="mapPanel" style="top: 0px; width: 98%; left: 10px; position: relative;" rendered="#{mappingSessionBean.displayMapPanel}" >
                            <p:gmap id="gmap" center="#{mappingSessionBean.mapCenter}" zoom="#{mappingSessionBean.mapZoom}" type="HYBRID" 
                                    style="#{mappingSessionBean.polygonGmapStyle}" fitBounds="#{mappingSessionBean.fitBoundsFlag}"
                                    model="#{mappingSessionBean.mapModel}" disableDoubleClickZoom="true"
                                    widgetVar="map" >
                                <p:ajax id="gmapAjax1" event="overlaySelect" listener="#{mappingSessionBean.onMapOverlaySelect}" update="@all :formEast:polyDetailPnl gmap messageComp:messagePnl :formCenter:mapPanel :formWest"  />
                                <p:ajax id="gmapAjax3" event="pointSelect" listener="#{mappingSessionBean.onMapPointSelect}" update="gmap" />
                                <p:ajax id="gmapAjax2" event="stateChange" listener="#{mappingSessionBean.onMapStateChange}" />
                                <p:ajax id="gmapAjax4" event="markerDrag" listener="#{mappingSessionBean.onMapMarkerDrag}" update="gmap" />
                            </p:gmap>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </h:form >
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="205" resizable="true" collapsible="true" header="Polygons" >
                <h:form id="formEast" prependId="=false" >
                    <p:outputPanel id="panelEast"   >
                        <h:panelGrid id="grid2" columns="1" style="height: 500px; width: 96%; display: block;" >
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{mappingSessionBean.displayAllPolygons}" >
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{mappingSessionBean.displayAllPolyAction}" update="@form :formCenter:gmap polyTable" />
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                <h:outputText id="txt2" value=" Select all (Checked = visible)" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <!-- p:outputPanel id="panel2" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 300px; display: block; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; overflow: auto;" -->
                            <p:dataTable id="polyTable" var="polys" style="width: 98%;" value="#{mappingSessionBean.polyDataList}" rowKey="#{polys.name}" 
                                         paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10"
                                         selection="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyData}" selectionMode="single" >
                                <p:column headerText="" style="width: 20px;"  >
                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{polys.visible}" >
                                        <p:ajax listener="#{mappingSessionBean.visibleCheckBoxAjax(polys)}" update="@form :formCenter:gmap" />
                                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Name" >
                                    #{polys.name}
                                </p:column>
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyListener}" update="@form :formCenter:gmap" />
                            </p:dataTable>
                            <!-- /p:outputPanel -->
                            <h:outputText id="rxt3" value="Polygon Details" />
                            <p:outputPanel id="panel3" style="position: relative; width: 98%; height: 175px; display: block; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; overflow: auto;" >
                                <p:outputPanel id="polyDetailPnl" >
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
                                        <h:outputText value="Polygon Id: " />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyData.polygonId}" />
                                        <h:outputText value="Name: " />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyData.name}" />
                                        <h:outputText value="Active Flag: " />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyData.active}" />
                                        <h:outputText value="Color: " />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyData.lineColor}" />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" >
                                        <h:outputText value="Polygon Points:  Lat., Lon." />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{mappingSessionBean.selectedPolyPoints}" escape="false" />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </h:form >
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" widgetVar="confirmDialog" header="Confirm Polygon Add / Update / Disable" message="#{mappingSessionBean.polyConfirmMsg}" >
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" style="margin-left: 10px;" actionListener="#{mappingSessionBean.confirmAddPolyContinueAction}" oncomplete="confirmDialog.hide();" update=":formCenter:gmap :formCenter:messageComp:messagePnl" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" style="margin-left: 25px;" actionListener="#{mappingSessionBean.confirmAddPolyQuitAction}" oncomplete="confirmDialog.hide();" update="@form :formCenter:gmap" />
            </h:form>
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:body>
</html>
</f:view>
```